# how to check if a nested list has had its base values changed

Tags: python, list

I can't think of a way to check if every value in my nested list has changed from its base number in this case 0, how would I do that?

`game_board = [ [0,0,0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0,] ]`

Comment: Do you mean you want to check whether all values are zero? If yes, is the nesting always one level deep?

Comment: There is no "base" value; the object doesn't distinguish between its current value and its initial value in anyway. You either need a separate object to compare against, or your code has to have the initial value hard-coded into your comparison algorithm.

Comment: yes I want to check if all values are 0 or not and the list will always be just like how I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

In case the nesting level is only one and you want to check whether there are numbers other than zero in your list, you can issue:

```
>>> any(x for sublist in game_board for x in sublist)
False
```

Alternatively, with another assumption about the length of the "base list":

```
>>> base = [0, 0, 0]
>>> any(sublist != base for sublist in game_board)
False
```

Or with numpy:

```
>>> np.count_nonzero(game_board) != 0
False
```